# Does atomic guarantee visibility ? JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading

I was reading this statement :

> The Java language specification guarantees that reading or writing a variable is an atomic operation(unless the variable is of type long or double). Operations variables of type long or double are only atomic if they declared with the volatile keyword.

now I wonder if I need really to use volatile on "int" or any variable that is not long or double for example considering it's atomic, are the changes to that variable guaranteed to be visible by other thread ?

---

What I want to understand if that atomic guarantees visibility for other thread without using volatile.

Comment: It seems to say that long/double operations are *atomic* if the variable is *volatile*. It does **not** say that int variables are inherently volatile.

Comment: It says that _reading or writing a variable_ of a variable (of type `int`) is an atomic operation (i.e. you can never observe it reading or writing two halves separately). It doesn't say that _changes_ are atomic.

Comment: There is literally nothing about visibility in the quote.

Comment: @Sweeper what I want to understand is if that atomic guarantees visibility for other threads.

Comment: "atomic" will guarantee that a thread always reads a complete change at once, but not that it reads every change from another thread at the right time (e.g. due to register read optimiziations). `volatile` ensures that a thread reads in a field "freshly" from memory before an operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An atomic write means that all the bits of a value a transfered from the CPU core into memory in one chunk. An atomic read means similarly that all the bits of a value are transfered from the memory into the CPU core in one chunk.

A non-atomic write or read means that the value is transfered in two (or more) separate chunks.

---

Consider a field

```
long someField = 0x00000000_12345678;
```

and two threads: thread one reads that field at the same time thread two updates that field to `0x12345678_00000000`.

With non-atomic reads and writes the following can happen:

- thread two writes the first 32 bits to memory (0x12345678)
- thread one reads the first 32 bits from memory (0x12345678)
- thread one reads the second 32 bits from memory (0x12345678)
- thread two writes the second 32 bits to memory (0x00000000)

After this sequence, the value that thread one has read is 0x12345678_12345678 - a value that was never written as a whole.

The statement in the JLS states that for `long` and `double` this can happen unless you declare the field as `volatile`.

It also states that a similar behaviour for all other types will never occur. For example with `int` values:

```
int someOtherField = 0x1234_0000;
```

and one thread reading that field while another thread updates that field to 0x0000_1234: the value that the first thread reads will either be 0x1234_0000 or 0x0000_1234.

---

For non-volatile fields however another outcome is possible (not related to atomicity, but to `volatile` fields):

```
while (someOtherField == 0x1234_0000) {
    // do something
}
```

A thread executing this piece of code is allowed to read the field only once and evaluate the condition to `true`, even if some other thread later changes the value of `someOtherField`.

---

Why did the designers of Java use the `volatile` designator to also guarantee atomic reads and writes of `long` and `double`?

Probably because they didn't want to introduce another designator for "these values must be read and written atomically".

Either your code cares about values (of type double or long) being written atomically - and then you are working with different threads, so you are most probably also interested in these changed values being visible to other threads, so you need the field to be volatile anyway.

Or the values are only accessed from a single thread - in this case atomicity is not required (because reading both halves and writing both halves are never interleaved) and visibility in other threads is also not required.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, volatile provides the following 3 properties:

- atomicity
- ordering
- visibility

As Thomas Klager already explained, atomicity guarantees that an operation is atomic so isn't some interleaving of other operations like torn read or write. This is only a problem on 32 bits JVMs in combination with long/doubles.

Ordering guarantees that surrounding loads and stores are ordered. E.g.:

```
int a;
volatile int b;

thread1(){
   a=1; 
   b=1;
}

thread2(){
    while(b==0);
    print("a=:"+a);
}
```

Can it happen that a=0 is printed? In the above example this can't happen because the 'b' orders the accesses to 'b'. But if 'b' would be a plain variable, then the 'a=0' could be printed.

The last one is visibility. So will a write to a variable on one CPU, be seen on another CPU? On modern hardware visibility isn't a concern because caches are coherent and store buffers eventually get written to the coherent cache. It is mostly a compiler concern, e.g the compiler could optimize this:

```
boolean stop;

thread1(){
   while(!stop){
      print("loop");
   }
}

thread2(){
  stop = true;
}
```

To:

```
boolean stop;

thread1(){
   if(!stop){
      while(true){
         print("loop");
      }
   }
}

thread2(){
  stop = true;
}
```

Now it is clear that this loop never needs to see the updated stop value. With volatile, such compiler optimizations are prohibited.